# How to integrate Saxon with Kafka

Tags: xslt, apache-kafka, publish-subscribe, middleware, saxon

I would like to use [Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/) as the kernel of my message-oriented middleware.

It means that, in addition to the transport of messages provided by Kafka, I would need **payload transformation/enrichment** between the payload sent by the producer and the payload received by the consumer. Indeed, in a lot of use cases, the format used by the producers will not be the most appropriate format for the consumers.

An obvious example would be having mainframe application producing COBOL copybooks as producer, and a node application optimized for JSON-based format as consumer! Or more commonly, two applications using XML syntax, but with different schemas.

In (traditional) message-oriented middleware, such payload transformation are usually performed by [XSLT](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt), which is a dedicated and performant language for transforming XML documents into other XML documents. And [Saxon](http://www.saxonica.com/html/download/opensource.html) is one of the leading XSLT processor in the market.

***Now, I am looking for advices/examples of how to integrate Saxon with Kafka... any hints/remarks/directions even questions would be appreciated!***

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, from the Saxonica end we cannot help you with this. We have no experience of Kafka.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Michael, even if I would obviously preferred another one... BTW, I would recommend to have a look at Apache Kafka - https://kafka.apache.org/